# PLUIPrivacyViewController and Access to photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

when i ask to show imagePicker with Photos from PhotoAlbum i get crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/9D75B5EC-6CC9-4306-B4A1-88C369FEEC6C/AlterGeo.app> (loaded)' with name 'PLUIPrivacyViewController''


- (void)showImagePicker {
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   if ([imagePicker respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsEditing:)]) {
      [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:_editable];
   }
   [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
   [[self getNavigationController] presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
   [imagePicker release];
}

- (UINavigationController *)getNavigationController {
   if (_delegate && [_delegate isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
      return [(UIViewController *)_delegate navigationController];
   }   
   return nil;
}
```

If it first launch and i ios ask for permissions (UIAlertView allow/deny) it will be crash, but if i have already granted permissons (allow) it will be work fine. 
How i can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution of my problem.
The code is not mine, it was outsource people with strange relisation of project.. anyway they ask for every ViewController xib file in category for UiViewController

```
- (NSString *)nibName {
   if ( ! [NSStringFromClass([self class]) isEqualToAnyString:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                               @"UIStatusBarViewController", 
                                                               @"UIZoomViewController",
                                                               @"PLUIPrivacyViewController",
                                                               nil]]) {
      return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
   }
   return nil;
}
```

and in ios6.0 apple added PLUIPrivacyViewController whitch dont have own nib.. I just add PLUIPrivacyViewController in exceptions..
Ofcource better way to make white list of controllers6 cuz the project is realy old and will not modify, but apple can add some other controllesrs without nibs... 
But its  lot of time.